# merging data frames by conditions and saving common values belonging to the same column efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that I want to merge by the following condition

1. A common value between one column between the 2 data frame
   `.query("CHROM == Chromosome_hg38")`
2. Region of one value between the regions of the other value
   `.query('START.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38) | END.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38)')`

These are my data frames:

```
data = [['chr1', 1,10,'Gene1','ID1'], ['chr2',15,20,'Gene2','ID2'],['chr2',21,40,'Gene3','ID3']]
LOUEF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Chromosome_hg38', 'Gene_start_hg38', 'Gene_stop_hg38','Gene_name','geneID'])
LOUEF

Chromosome_hg38 Gene_start_hg38 Gene_stop_hg38  Gene_name   geneID
0   chr1        1               10              Gene1        ID1
1   chr2        15              20              Gene2        ID2
2   chr2        21              40              Gene3        ID3
```

```
data2 = [['chr1', 3,11,'location1'], ['chr1',11,17,'location2'],['chr2',20,30,'location3'],['chr2',15,17,'location3'],['chr5',1,19,'location4']]
cnvs = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['CHROM', 'START', 'END','locations'])


CHROM   START   END locations
0   chr1    3   11  location1
1   chr1    11  17  location2
2   chr2    20  30  location3
3   chr2    15  17  location3
4   chr5    1   19  location4
```

The code I am using

```
cnvs['Gene_name'] = (
    cnvs.loc[cnvs['CHROM'].isin(LOUEF['Chromosome_hg38'])]   
       .reset_index().merge(LOUEF, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_'))
       .query("CHROM == Chromosome_hg38")
       .query('START.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38) | END.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38)')
       .groupby('index')['Gene_name'].apply(list).str.join(';')
)
```

With this code I got this

```
CHROM   START   END locations   Gene_name
0   chr1    3   11  location1   Gene1
1   chr1    11  17  location2   NaN
2   chr2    20  30  location3   Gene2;Gene2
3   chr2    15  17  location3   Gene2
4   chr5    1   19  location4   NaN
```

As I have done with gene_name, how could I do the same with geneID without the need of repeat the same code again?

```
CHROM   START   END locations   Gene_name    geneID
0   chr1    3   11  location1   Gene1        ID1
1   chr1    11  17  location2   NaN          NaN
2   chr2    20  30  location3   Gene2;Gene2  ID2;ID2
3   chr2    15  17  location3   Gene2        ID2
4   chr5    1   19  location4   NaN          NaN
```

Comment: maybe put the string names in a list and iterate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way?

```
for key in ("Gene_name", "geneID"):
    cnvs[key] = (
        cnvs.loc[cnvs['CHROM'].isin(LOUEF['Chromosome_hg38'])]   
           .reset_index().merge(LOUEF, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_'))
           .query("CHROM == Chromosome_hg38")
           .query('START.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38) | END.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38)')
           .groupby('index')[key].apply(list).str.join(';')
    )
```